# Why are there no rake tasks in this mongoid Rails 3 project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, mongoid

https://github.com/memphis518/Garden-Dating-Service

The public repo above is a community coding project we're working on for Austin Community Gardens, and it's a fairly simple project so far, but for some reason `rake db:seed` doesn't work ("Don't know how to build task db:seed"), and when you run `rake -T` it reveals *no* rake tasks at all.

MongoID documentation says it provides most of the usual DB-related rake tasks - I can't figure out why they're not there.

Answer (score 6):

I had the similar problem with Rails 3.X, although the mongoid Gem was included in my Gemfile. I could solve the problem by explicitly requiring the database.rake file from the mongoid gem. I added this 2 lines to my Rakefile:

```
spec = Gem::Specification.find_by_name 'mongoid'
load "#{spec.gem_dir}/lib/mongoid/railties/database.rake"
```

That works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering because I had it as well in my Gemfile :D

Answer (score 3):

Had the exact same issue.

Realized I never added "mongoid" to my Gemfile. This fixes it:

```
gem 'mongoid'
```

It will add these rake tasks:

```
rake db:drop                    # Drops all the collections for the database for the current Rails.env
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes  # Create the indexes defined on your mongoid models
rake db:mongoid:drop            # Drops the database for the current Rails.env
rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes  # Remove the indexes defined on your mongoid models without questions!
rake db:reseed                  # Delete data and seed
rake db:seed                    # Load the seed data from db/seeds.rb
rake db:setup                   # Create the database, and initialize with the seed data
```

Comment: I've definitely got mongoid in the Gemfile.  Still not working, oddly - try cloning it and see for yourself! ;)

Comment: Did you try "bundle update" or "bundle install" to make sure the mongoid gem was installed

Comment: worked for me. I assumed they would be added since I have mongoid as a dependency in a gemspec.